# MS pnp Taxonomy Control rendering on bottom

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, sharepoint

I was trying to use the taxonomy control on my simple page. However, it always renders on the bottom of the page. The hidden field stays where it is, but the taxonomy control is always on the bottom.

On the rendered page I always have Test and blubb together and the taxonomy control comes after it:
Test
blubb
[Control]

Is there any known bug why this happens?

```
    <%@ Assembly Name="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.ApplicationPages" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="asp" Namespace="System.Web.UI" Assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %>
<%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="t.aspx.cs" Inherits="sptaxpicker2.Layouts.sptaxpicker2.t" DynamicMasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="PageHead" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderAdditionalPageHead" runat="server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/taxonomypickercontrol.css">
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="scripts/taxonomypickercontrol.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <script>
        //Wait for the page to load
        $(document).ready(function () {

            //Get the URI decoded SharePoint site url from the SPHostUrl parameter.
            var spHostUrl = "http://sp2013";
            var appWebUrl = "http://sp2013/sites/dev";
            var spLanguage = "en-us";

            //Build absolute path to the layouts root with the spHostUrl
            var layoutsRoot = spHostUrl + '/_layouts/15/';

            //load all appropriate scripts for the page to function
            $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.Runtime.js',
                function () {
                    $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.js',
                        function () {
                            //Load the SP.UI.Controls.js file to render the Add-In Chrome
                            //$.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.UI.Controls.js', renderSPChrome);

                            //load scripts for cross-domain calls
                            //$.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'SP.RequestExecutor.js', function () {
                            //    context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);
                            //    var factory = new SP.ProxyWebRequestExecutorFactory(appWebUrl);
                            //    context.set_webRequestExecutorFactory(factory);
                            //});

                            context = new SP.ClientContext(appWebUrl);

                            //load scripts for calling taxonomy APIs
                            $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'init.js',
                                function () {
                                    $.getScript(layoutsRoot + 'sp.taxonomy.js',
                                        function () {
                                            $('#txbox').taxpicker({
                                                isMulti: false,
                                                allowFillIn: false,
                                                termSetId: 'bed6c3ef-4eac-4bfb-9809-94112e7ba0c2'
                                            }, context);
                                        });
                                });
                        });
                });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
   test<br /> <input type="hidden" id="txbox" /><br />blubb

</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitle" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitle" runat="server">
simple test
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="PageTitleInTitleArea" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderPageTitleInTitleArea" runat="server" >
simpletest
</asp:Content>
```

Thanks!
Best,
Christian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found: It is important to put the control inside a container like a div and not directly as a table data because the javascript behind uses parent element to move the item.